# Why PageSpeed Insights is not updating/changing my webpage Discover what your real users are experiencing?

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I am checking my webpage PageSpeed to sortout my CLS problems but it is not showing any change in 'Discover what your real users are experiencing' section. Now i am checking empty link and it is showing same results

i am expecting change in 'real users are experiencing' section but there not any change, even on empty link

Comment: Need more details. Can you explain what you mean by “empty link”? And what changes are you expecting? Did you make improvements? If so, what did you improve and by how much? And when? Can you edit your question to give more details.